# how to arcgis javascript vertex undoManager

Tags: javascript, arcgis

I try to undo / redo the edit vertex using undomanager.

Graphic objects are tested. But I do not know what to do Edit vertex  undo / redo.

Is it possible the vertex undo / redo?

I looked to find many examples have not found the answer.

i`m korean beginner programmer. help me~ T.T

```
   function initEditing(evt) {
      console.log("initEditing", evt);
      var currentLayer = null;
      var layers = arrayUtils.map(evt.layers, function(result) {
        return result.layer;
        console.log("result ==== "+result);
      });
      console.log("layers", layers);

       editToolbar = new Edit(map);
      editToolbar.on("deactivate", function(evt) {
          console.log("deactivate !!!! ");
        currentLayer.applyEdits(null, [evt.graphic], null);
      });

      arrayUtils.forEach(layers, function(layer) {
        var editingEnabled = false;
        layer.on("dbl-click", function(evt) {
          event.stop(evt);
          if (editingEnabled === false) {
            editingEnabled = true;
            editToolbar.activate(Edit.EDIT_VERTICES , evt.graphic);
            pre_evt = evt.graphic;
            editToolbar.on("vertex-move-stop", function(evt){
                console.log("vertex-move-stop~");
                g_evt = evt;
                console.log("evt.transform ===== " +evt.transform);
                var operation = new esri.dijit.editing.Update({
                    featureLayer : landusePointLayer,
                     preUpdatedGraphics:pre_evt,
                     postUpdatedGraphics: evt.graphic
                })
                 var operation = new CustomOperation.Add({
                                     graphicsLayer: pre_evt._graphicsLayer,
                                         addedGraphic: evt.graphic
                                       });
                                 undoManager.add(operation);
                console.log("operation ======== ",operation);
            });

            console.log("dbl-click  & eidt  true");
          } else {
            currentLayer = this;
            editToolbar.deactivate();
            editingEnabled = false;
            console.log("dbl-click  & eidt false ");
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The sample you are refering to, just gives you an idea how you can use UndoManager. You need to create your own operations if you need undo/redo for vertices. Below I have provided one for AddVertex. You would need to create your own for other operations.

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare",  
        "esri/OperationBase"],
     function(declare, 
              OperationBase) {

    var customOp = {};

    customOp.AddVertex = declare(OperationBase, {
        label: "Add Vertex",
        _editedGraphic: null,
        _vertexInfo: null,
        _vertex: null,
        _editTool: null,

        constructor: function (params) {
            params = params || {};

            if (!params.editTool) {
                console.error("no edit toolbar provided");
                return;
            }
            this._editTool = params.editTool;

            if (!params.editedGraphic) {
                console.error("no graphics provided");
                return;
            }
            this._editedGraphic = params.editedGraphic;

            if (!params.vertexinfo) {
                console.error("no vertexinfo provided");
                return;
            }
            this._vertexInfo = params.vertexinfo;

            var geometry = this._editedGraphic.geometry;
            if(geometry.type === "multipoint") {
                this._vertex = geometry.getPoint(this._vertexInfo.pointIndex);
            } else if(geometry.type === "polyline" || geometry.type === "polygon") {
                this._vertex = geometry.getPoint(this._vertexInfo.segmentIndex, this._vertexInfo.pointIndex);
            } else {
                console.error("Not valid geometry type.");
            }
        },


        performUndo: function () {
            var geometry = this._editedGraphic.geometry;
            if(geometry.type === "multipoint"){
                geometry.removePoint(this._vertexInfo.pointIndex);
            } else if(geometry.type === "polyline" || geometry.type === "polygon") {
                geometry.removePoint(this._vertexInfo.segmentIndex, this._vertexInfo.pointIndex);
            }
            this._editedGraphic.draw();
            this._editTool.refresh();
        },

        performRedo: function () {
            var geometry = this._editedGraphic.geometry;
            if(geometry.type === "multipoint"){
                geometry.removePoint(this._vertexInfo.pointIndex, this._vertex);
            } else if(geometry.type === "polyline" || geometry.type === "polygon") {
                geometry.insertPoint(this._vertexInfo.segmentIndex, this._vertexInfo.pointIndex, this._vertex);
            }
            this._editedGraphic.draw();
            this._editTool.refresh();
        }
    });

    return customOp;
});
```

Make sure you clear the UndoManager when you deactivate the edit toolbar. Otherwise the Operations will remain. Do not combine the Add graphics operations with Vertex Operations. It will not work as they use different toolbar and edit toolbar state will be lost as soon as you deactive it.

One more thing to note is when you use the UndoManager, the graphics isModified state will always be true, since we are adding and deleting vertex during undo/redo, even if undo all changes. Hence, make sure you need to applyedit by checking if there are any pending undo (geometry is really modified).

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: glad to help, mark it as answered if it solved your problem.